# Overflow Error in VBA Despite Range Set to 3x Error Point

Tags: excel, vba

I keep getting an overflow error at this line `For i = b To b + a - 1` when I run this code. The error occurs when the data pasted exceeds 32,765 which is far below the 100,000 range I have set.

Can anyone see what the problem is?

Thanks

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Columns.Count <> 16 Then Exit Sub

    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set Target = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F2")
' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:P50")
 
  
If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then
           
'Count the cells to copy
Dim a As Integer
a = 0
For i = 5 To 50
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
a = a + 1
End If
Next i

'Count the last cell where to start copying
Dim b As Integer
b = 2
For i = 2 To 100000
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
b = b + 1
End If
Next i

Dim c As Integer
c = 5
'Perform the copy paste process
Application.EnableEvents = False
For i = b To b + a - 1

If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E2") <> "" And ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F2") = "" And ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AB5") = "35" Then
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 1) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 14)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 2) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 3) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 4) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 5)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 5) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c, 26)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 6) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c, 1)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 7) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c, 6)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 8) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c, 8)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 9) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c, 15)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 10) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c, 16)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 11) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 2)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 12) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c, 7)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 13) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c, 2)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 14) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c, 3)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 15) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c, 4)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 16) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c, 5)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 17) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c, 9)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 18) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c, 12)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 19) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c, 13)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 20) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c, 10)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 21) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c, 11)

c = c + 1
End If
Next i
Application.EnableEvents = True

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Integer` values in VBA go from -32,768 to +32,767.

If you want to go beyond +32,767 or below -32768, define your variables as `Long`, not `Integer`.
`Long` variables can go from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.

See [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic/Data_Types#Byte,_Integer_&_Long).

Comment: Thanks Romulax. That's sorted it.